# Curl error: option-less arguments found

Tags: rest, curl, postman, mailgun

I'm trying to import this example into postman

```
curl -s --user 'api:YOUR_API_KEY' \
    https://api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/messages \
    -F from='Excited User <mailgun@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME>' \
    -F to=YOU@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME \
    -F to=bar@example.com \
    -F subject='Hello' \
    -F text='Testing some Mailgun awesomness!'
```

Please help me understand the -s, --user, -F, what is that? And then when I try to import, I get this error: option-less arguments found. How can I fix this?

Comment: It would help if you'd show your **exact** output. curl itself never says "option-less arguments found". If you want to understand curl options, I recommend reading its [man page](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)

Comment: I don't really understand how to put the command on the curl command line in windows. I was using Postman.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you're trying to execute curl commands in Postman, select **Import**, then **Paste Raw Text** and then copy the command, but first remove all backslashes.

Comment: Thank you, those backslashes was it.